# Generating XML using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to fetch the following sample data to generate xml using sql query.

```
    SELECT 
    ClassId ID, 
    StudentLevel Code_level, 
    Code, 
    A.FullCode FullCode, 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(RollNo)) Rollno,
    a.SubjectID,
    (SELECT Description FROM CLS_DescriptionData WHERE DescriptionId = A.DescriptionID) Description,
    SUBSTRING(a.FullCode,0,Len(a.Fullcode)-Len(a.Code)+1) ParentCode 
    FROM (SELECT SubjectID, ClassId, StudentLevel, DescriptionID, Code, FullCode, SUBSTRING(FullCode,1,8) RootNode 
    FROM Rem_ClassHeader H JOIN Rem_ClassData D on H.ClassHeaderId = D.ClassHeaderId AND Version = 514 AND SubjectID = 'MAT11' ) A 
    JOIN Symptom_Rem_Code B on A.RootNode = B.FullCode AND A.SubjectID = B.SubjectID
    ORDER BY RollNo, A.FullCode
for xml path('sample', Root('DCD')
```

I want the data which is displayed from the above SQL query to be displayed in the below format of XML. Can someone please help me out of this.

```
    -<DCD Subject ="Mat11" Sampel="">        
      -<Pt LocatorNo="some code" someNo="some no.">        
         -<FaultType Description="some text" Value="A1">        
             -<Ddd Description="some text" Value="1A">        
                -<CC Description="Some text" Value="2D">        
                   <RC Description="some text" Value="01"/>        
                </CC>        
                -<CC Description="some text" Value="02">        
                   <RC Description="some text" Value="01"/>        
                </CC>                           
             </DC>        
      </pt>
    </DCD>
```

But what I am actually getting is in the following way

```
<DCD>
<ID>01</ID>
<StudentLevel>some data</StudentLevel>
<FullCode>Mat11</FullCode>
<RollNo>01</RollNo>
<ClassID>1</ClassID>
<Description>some data</Description>
<ParentCode>000000</ParentCode>
</DCD>
```

Comment: I have used the below query to generate xml so far

Comment: for xml path('sample'), Root('DCD')

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is being downvoted because the community feels you have not researched your problem sufficiently. You can improve the question by showing us what you have already tried - please _edit_ your question to add information to it, do not provide it in the comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The following query generates the XML as you needed,

```
select 'Mat11' as [DCD/@Subject],
'' as [DCD/@Sampel],
'some code' as [DCD/Pt/@LocatorNo],
'some no.' as [DCD/Pt/@someNo],
'some Text' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/@Description],
'Value' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/@Value],
'some Text' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/Ddd/@Description],
'Value' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/Ddd/@Value],
'CC Text' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/Ddd/CC/@Description],
'235' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/Ddd/CC/@Value],
'some Text' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/Ddd/CC/RC/@Description],
'01' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/Ddd/CC/RC/@Value],
'CC1 Text' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/Ddd/CC1/@Description],
'2' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/Ddd/CC1/@Value],
'some Text' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/Ddd/CC1/RC/@Description],
'02' as [DCD/Pt/FaultType/Ddd/CC1/RC/@Value]
for XML Path('')
```

In the `XML` you have shown there is a repeated parent Node name(`CC`) we cannot use it like that because The same attribute cannot be generated more than once on the same `XML tag`, so I used differant name(`CC1`) and made the `XML` like yours